# Does Scintillating Spell metamagic apply to cantrips (e.g., Electric Arc)?

Tags: spellcasting, pathfinder-2e, metamagic

I'm still learning the rules for PF2 but it seems that Electric Arc meets all the criteria for [Scintillating Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1829) metamagic (in bold):

> Your spells become a radiant display of light and color. **If your next action is to Cast a Spell that doesn't have the darkness trait, has no duration, and requires creatures to attempt a Reflex save, the spell explodes in a spray of scintillating lights, in addition to its other effects**. Each creature that failed its Reflex save against the spell is dazzled for 1 round, and those who critically failed are instead blinded for 1 round.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Scintillating Spell Works With Cantrips

You haven't missed some hidden rule here, the only requirements are those quoted from the [action](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1829):

- Next action is to [Cast a Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=72)
- Spell doesn't have the  darkness trait
- Spell has no duration
- Spell requires Reflex save(s)

*[Electric arc](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=97)* meets each of these requirements so it works with Scintillating Spell.

More broadly, **any** spell that meets those requirements also works with the metamagic feat, including [focus spells](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=276), [innate spells](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=279), or [cantrips](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=275).